# How do I add the nth element for every line in a text file?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, summation, text, mac-os-x

Suppose I have a text file, in this format:

```
1 1 1 1 1 99.5016 10.43 99.5016 99.5016 7.074 47.8012 10.43 7.074 7.074
2 1 1 1 1 99.5016 10.43 99.5016 99.5016 7.074 47.8012 10.43 7.074 7.074
3 1 1 1 1 99.5016 10.43 99.5016 99.5016 7.074 47.8012 10.43 7.074 7.074
```

And I want to add up all the elements in the ones column, for a certain number of lines.  How would I do that?

I have this currently:

```
data = Import[
  "/Users/myname/Documents/foldername/filename.txt", "Table"]
Total@data[[All, 2]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html), [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (i.e. `[[...]]`), probably [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) (i.e. `;;`), and [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html).

Import the data:

```
data = Import["path\to\yourdatafile.txt", "Table"];
```

Sum all entries in the first column:

```
Total@data[[All, 1]]
```

Sum entries in the third column and in the second to third row:

```
Total@data[[2 ;; 3, 3]]
```

Sum entries in column 2, rows 1 and 3:

```
Total@data[[{1, 3}, 2]]
```

Comment: I believe I did everything you mentioned, but it doesn't produce an output.

    data=Import["textfile", "Table"];
    Total@data[[2;;10000,2]];
    (If I wanted to add up everything in the second column)

Comment: @Ihaveaquestion Well, I took your sample data and copied in a text file, then ran the code exactly as shown, just substituting the correct path, and obtained [these results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ksttZ.png). I suspect that perhaps the format of the file is not as you expect it, or the numbers are not stored in a simple form. Could you share the exact contents of your data file?

Comment: There are 10k lines in my text file, so I don't think I can fit that here.  The elements in each line are separated by a single space, and each line has 13 elements.

Comment: @Ihaveaquestion Then perhaps you could show the first few here, just to make sure of format, then provide a link to the whole file (pastebin, filetea, dropbox, github, etc).

Comment: replaced original question's lines with 3 actual lines from my file

Comment: @Ihaveaquestion It seems to work fine with the new file contents too: [results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ENk.png). Can you try running `data=Import["textfile", "Table"]` WITHOUT the semicolon, to make sure that data is being imported correctly? Also try `And @@ Flatten@Map[NumberQ, data, {2}]`, which should return True if all elements of your file have been correctly imported as numbers.

Comment: I checked the import, it seems to be working fine.
Getting the error "part 2 of {} does not exist"

Also, added in what I have in mathematica right now into original question

Comment: Also tried the
    And @@ Flatten@Map[NumberQ, data, {2}]
and it returned true

Comment: Perhaps the syntax is different on Mac?  This is what I get when I run Total@data[[All,2]]

http://imgur.com/WEv3YhY

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
data = Import[
  "/Users/myname/Documents/foldername/filename.txt", "Table"]
Total[data, {1}]
```

Part of the error was that I had an empty row at the end of my text file.